# Double integral does not converge

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate the double integral c

```
f1[R0_, m_] := BesselJ[0, (m*R)/R0]*(Cosh[4.8*z]/Cosh[4.8/2] - Cos[4.8*z]/Cos[4.8/2]); 
c[R0_, m_] := Integrate[f1[R0, m]*(D[f1[R0, m], {R, 4}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 3}]/R + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 3}]/R + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}]/R^2 + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}] + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + D[f1[R0, m], {z, 4}]), {R, 0, R0}, {z, -(1/2), 1/2}]
c[1, 3.83171]
```

The output of this says that c does not converge, however, when I change the order of the integrals, then I am getting a value. Which one is supposed to be the correct answer and how can I verify this?

Answer (score 1):

Putting exact values in the definition of `f1` (e.g. 4.8 -> 48/10 etc.) and adding the assumption `m>=0` appears to fix this problem and get rid of all warning and error messages (just takes a minute or so to evaluate):

```
f1[R0_, m_] := 
  BesselJ[0, (m*R)/R0]*(Cosh[48/10*z]/Cosh[48/20] - 
     Cos[48/10*z]/Cos[48/20]);
integrand = 
  f1[R0, m]*(D[f1[R0, m], {R, 4}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 3}]/R + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 3}]/R + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}]/R^2 + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + 
     D[f1[R0, m], {z, 4}]);

c[R0_, m_] = 
 Integrate[integrand, {R, 0, R0}, {z, -(1/2), 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> m >= 0];
c[1, 3.83171]
(*384.273*)
```

**Add-on:** Changing the order of integration has no effect anymore on the output BUT you have to change `m>=0` to `m>0` so there is some issue with $\lim_{m\to0}$

```
c2[R0_, m_] = 
 Integrate[integrand, {z, -(1/2), 1/2}, {R, 0, R0}, 
  Assumptions -> m > 0];
c2[R0, m] === c[R0, m]
(*True*)
```

Comment: `Series[integrand, {R, 0, 1}]` produces `-((m^2 (-Cos[(24 z)/5] Sec[12/5] + Cosh[(24 z)/5] Sech[12/5])^2)/(
  2 R0^2 R^2)) +...`, idicating the divergence at a line `R==0`.

Comment: I didn't look at expansion of `integrand`, but I did notice that the limit is `Indeterminate` at `R==0` if you integrate w.r.t R:

`intR = Integrate[integrand, R];`


`Limit[intR, R -> 0]`

`(*Indeterminate*)`

Answer (score 1):

Sympolic integration of the z-part evaluates to

```
intz=Integrate[integrand, {z, -(1/2), 1/2} ]
```

Next integration step

```
Integrate[intz, {R,0,R0} ]
```

gives error message `integral ...does not converge on {0,R0}`

Also the asymptotic estimation

```
Asymptotic[intz, R -> 0] // Factor
```

$\frac{m^2 \sec ^2\left(\frac{12}{5}\right) \left(-29-96 e^{24/5}-19 e^{48/5}+5 \sin \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)+10 e^{24/5} \sin
   \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)+5 e^{48/5} \sin \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-5 \cos \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-48 e^{24/5} \cos
   \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)+5 e^{48/5} \cos \left(\frac{24}{5}\right)\right)}{96 \left(1+e^{8/5}\right)^2 \left(1-e^{8/5}+e^{16/5}\right)^2
   R^2 \text{R0}^2}$

indicates `Integral[1/R^2 ...,{R,0,R0}]` divergence (see @user64494'answer)!

Comment: You demonstrate the divergence of an iterated integral, no more and no less. The question is about  the divergence/convergence of a double integral.

Comment: Perhaps it's a goog oppertunity to  read  again `Fubini's theorem` (your citation) .I'm out of this useless discussion

Comment: Glad you master your math.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
Series[f1[R0, m]*(D[f1[R0, m],{R, 4}]+D[f1[R0, m],{R, 3}]/R+D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}]+
D[f1[R0, m], {R, 3}]/R + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}]/R^2 +  D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + 
D[f1[R0, m], {R, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1[R0, m], {R, 1}, {z, 2}]/R + 
D[f1[R0, m], {z, 4}]), {R, 0, 1}]
```

results in

> $$-\frac{0.919541 \left(m^2 (1. \cos (4.8 z)+0.132698 \cosh (4.8 z))^2\right)}{R^2 \text{R0}^2}+(1.35613 \cos (4.8 z)+0.179955 \cosh (4.8 z)) \left(\frac{1.94943 m^4 (1. \cos (4.8 z)+0.132698 \cosh (4.8 z))}{\text{R0}^4}-\frac{2 m^2 (4.14616 \cosh (4.8 z)-31.2452 \cos (4.8 z))}{\text{R0}^2}+719.889 \cos (4.8 z)+95.5276 \cosh (4.8 z)\right)+O\left(R^2\right) $$

This clearly shows that the double integral under consideration diverges on its singular line `R==0`. The difference between the iterated integrals confirms it (see [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for info).